# is /dev/dm-1 a partition or a whole block device?

Tags: linux-kernel, devices, device-mapper

Is there a way to figure out if `/dev/dm-1` is a block device partition or a whole block device? If `/dev/dm-1` is a partition, is there a way to find out the path to the corresponding whole block device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given dm-x with major M, minor m, there is a corresponding `/sys/dev/block/M:m/dm/uuid` file. If the content of the `uuid` file starts with `part`, it is safe to assume it is a partition. The corresponding whole device is found in `/sys/dev/block/M:n/slaves/`. For instance:

```
[centos@try ~]$ cat /sys/dev/block/253:0/dm/uuid
mpath-353333330000007d0
[centos@try ~]$ cat /sys/dev/block/253:1/dm/uuid
part1-mpath-353333330000007d0
[centos@try ~]$ ls -l /sys/dev/block/253:1/slaves
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 0 15 août  22:06 dm-0 -> ../../dm-0
```

Answer (score 15):

Every partition is a "whole" block-device.
You *could* sub-partition any partition, and then sub-partition it again, and again ...

In your example `dm-1` could be mapped to anything, a raw device, a dmcrypt device abstraction, a logical volume on a MD-RAID-backed, multi-pathed, dm-crypted volume group.

The number `dm-X` basically was just an arbitrary free number when the device was initialized. On hosts without many changes in the block device layer during runtime these numbers are just allocated in natural order at bootup.

But most device mapper mechanisms also allow you to specify an alias for your mapping. Check out `ls -l /dev/mapper/`.

To then visualize the hierarchical relationships between block devices you can use the `lsblk` (List block-devices). Shortened example output below:

```
$ lsblk /dev/sdb
NAME                   MAJ:MIN  TYPE
sdb                      8:128  disk
├─sdb1                   8:129  part
└─sdb5                   8:133  part
  └─crypto (dm-0)        252:0  crypt
    ├─ubuntu-root (dm-1) 252:1  lvm
    └─ubuntu-swap (dm-2) 252:2  lvm
```

Answer (score 6):

The [lsblk](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/lsblk.8.html) command is a convenient way of displaying information about block devices including which device mapper device goes where.

Answer (score 2):

/dev/dm-1 is for "device mapper n.1".

Basically, it is a logical unit carved out using the kernel embedded device mapper layer. From a userspace application point of view, it is a RAW block device.

Using `pvs` and `lvdisplay` we should be able to tell you the specific physical disk/partition backing it.

Comment: device-mapper is used for a lot more than just LVM.  Assuming `pvs` and `lvdisplay` will show you the details of any given `dm-X` device is not a good assumption.

Comment: True, but I shot for the common case first...